# Meaning of Samsung bootloader codenames?

Tags: samsung, bootloader, android-versions

I realized that you cannot install firmware with older bootloader version than the one in the device.

To do things more correctly and safely, I want more fully understand the bootloader codename meaning.

Here are diffrent bootloader codenames, that appear in different three Build Numbers.

> 1. Build Number: G965FXX**U7D**TB4 
>    Bootloader Codename: `U7D`
> 2. Build Number: G965U1UE**S7D**TB2 
>    Bootloader Codename: `S7D`
> 3. Build Number: G965USQ**U6C**SI2 
>    Bootloader Codename: `U6C`

I understand  that the digit between the two letter indicated the bootloader version. 
Therefore, the bootloader version is the same for `U7D` and `S7D` and the `U6C` is older.

However, it is not the same codename.

What is the difference between `U7D` and `S7D`?
I'd love to know what the diffrent letters means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference between U7D and S7D?

First, the difference between `U` and `S`:

> The x is either a U or a S. U updates tend to have actual updates and/or new features. Or simply bug fixes. S updates tend to be strictly security-related.

Secondly, the meaning of `7`:

> This is the bootloader number/fuse. What you need to know: You cannot rollback to a version that has a bootloader fuse lower than the version you currently have. As such, if you have a 3 BL fuse, you cannot go back to a 2 BL fuse. But you can go forward to a 4 BL.

Finally, the meaning of `D`

> is the software upgrade version. The first version is always A. When there is a major update, such as a feature update or an Android upgrade, this letter goes up. Note that for official beta versions, the letter is always Z.

All the above quotes are from [How to read build versions](https://r1.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S/How-to-read-build-versions/td-p/581424).